# Best interpolation technique for ODE-data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, estimation, curve-fitting, interpolation

Let's assume we have an ODE $\dot{x}=F(x)$ where $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field. And we observe a trajectory $\gamma: [t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ from this ODE but just a finite number of data points $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_N\}$. These data points might have some noise.

My goal is to estimate integrals of the form
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\gamma_i(t)\gamma_j(t)dt$$
directly from the data points. To do so, I need to interpolate the data.

My question is the following: Is there a know best practice to interpolate data coming from an ODE? When noise is added, should I fit e.g. a NN to each coordinate function $\gamma_i$ instead of using an interpolation scheme?